# LEFT JOIN FIlter

Tags: sql, teradata

If I have two tables - `Table_A` and `Table_B` - and if I am using `LEFT JOIN` to join them, how can I filter only those rows from `Table_B` which joined with the rows in the `Table_A` more than once?

DB flavor: Teradata

Comment: Do you mean, GROUP BY?

Comment: GROUP BY and HAVING count() > 1

Comment: sorry, I have to correct the question - I have to filter all the rows from the Table_B which participated in the join more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken Teradata supports window functions, so this might work:

```
select *
from (
  select a.*, 
         b.*
         count(*) over (partition by a.MyCol) as cnt
  from Table_A a
     left join Table_B b ON a.MyCol = b.MyCol 
  where ... -- Conditions
) t
where cnt > 1
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Teradata-specific version of your accepted answer:

```
select a.*, 
       b.*
from Table_A a
left join Table_B b 
ON a.MyCol = b.MyCol 
where ... -- Conditions
QUALIFY count(*) over (partition by a.MyCol) > 1
```

Note that `QUALIFY` is a Teradata extension to the ANSI standard (and a handy one at that).

Answer (score 0):

may be it's help for you

```
1) you can used INNER JOIN .
2) you can also check joind row is not null or blank .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.*,b.* from Table_A a
left join Table_B b on condition
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.value)>1
```

make necessary edits and check